# how can i create an excel file using Interop on c++

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, interop, excel-2007

I've searched a lot of info, about the easiest way to create and edit excel files to save some login and passwords of my program. I've seen lots of C# methods and I don't understand it a lot.

I've added a reference to Visual Studio 2010 `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` (I'm using Office 2010).

I don't know how to take this further, however; what headers should I add, what else should I do? I can't find any tutorial of C++ using this on their projects. I just want something simple.

**EDIT:**

I will run my program on a pc that has Office 2010 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read these

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686/en-us?fr=1

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/microsoftexcel/article.php/c11745/Microsoft-Excel-Automation-Class.htm

Comment: i aprecciete this answer, but the first one, its the hard way. I mean, that will work on all the pcs(installed or not installed the Oficce), i already added the reference of oficce to my project but idk what else i have to do. Cause when i add the using namespace Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel; it gives me an error

Comment: I fixed it now, i got a problem with the define and the Reference, they got the same name! it worked thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Does the system where your application will run on have Excel installed or not?

If it does, you can use indeed use Excel as a COM component.  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-c](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=26137) contains an example on how to do this.

If your system does not have Excel installed, you need to use a 3rd party library to create the Excel files for you.  Just Google for "create excel files without excel" and you will find dozens of example code.

Comment: The link is dead :(

Comment: Found another page with an example, this time from Microsoft.  Replaced the link in the answer.