# Reading the cells of an excel sheet in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

In one of my program, I'm suppose to parse an excel sheet using C++ programming. I'm not suppose to use any third party tool. So, please let me know the code to parse excel sheet and read rows and columns of an selected excel sheet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a .csv file - which is comma separated values.
 Each cell is separated with a comma, and each row is ended with a CR ( endl)

Comment: I have tried fstream but we cant pase the excel file, cell wise using that.

Comment: For this purpose you have to use as least `MS - Office Library` including `dll` and `tlb` files.

Comment: Hi Ankit, could you please let me more about that. Thank you.

Comment: @kernel how would we convert `excel` to `csv`. can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: Change it to `CSV` first or try `LibXL` if you change your mind to use 3rd party library.

Comment: Ankit, I believe changing the extension of excel from .xls to .csv, we can change the files from excel to csv files. But my question is is there any other methods.

Comment: @user3164377 Which IDE you are using

Comment: @AnkitB export as csv?

Comment: @user3164377 only by changing the extension does not change the whole file to csv

Comment: @user3164377 There is a one way to do this is by `Office automation` by automating excel. But it will use third party software i.e. `MS-Office`

Answer (score 2):

In order to read excel files you need some external tool like `MS - Office Library`. Why don't you export excel to CSV (Comma Seperated File) `File->Save as->CSV(Comma Delimited)`.

Then you can read it just like normal txt file. You can open and edit just like worksheet in MS-Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can COM to access Excel; for an example, see http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=26137 (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909422/how-can-i-create-an-excel-file-using-interop-on-c) question)

However to will probably be easier to use C++/CLI as a wrapper and access COM from .NET.